# Aligning the text in Legend in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Currently the legend aligns the text to the left. I.e (-- indicates item label and in most cases would be just different colors.

```
 ___________________
[-- Legend item 2   ]
[-- Legend item 3   ]
[-- Legend item 244 ]
```

I would like it so that it does it it like this

```
 ___________________
[--   Legend item 2 ] 
[--   Legend item 3 ]
[-- Legend item 244 ]
```

I tried playing around with itemStyle: textAlign: 'right' but no luck. Is this even possible?

Comment: Hi, Have u done legend's title alignment (with in the box), I mean aligning the title left, center or right ? If yes please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set useHTML and then define width and text-align:

http://jsfiddle.net/5gjfW/2/

```
.highcharts-legend-item span {
    width:70px!important;
    text-align:right!important;
}
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.useHTML

Comment: yes this does exactly what i wanted. however, when I implement this solution using the GWT wrapper, I cannot click on the legend items anymore. would you happen to know why? it works in the jsfiddle.

Comment: i used legend.setOption("useHTML", "true") and that seems to remove and event handling with the legendItem