# Highcharts.js legend items align

Tags: highcharts

I have a pie chart. As you can see items of the legend next to each other.
[image]

---

Is it possible to align the legend items in two columns?
[image]

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Provide us some code, you can use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or check something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293332/aligning-the-text-in-legend-in-highcharts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `legend` with properly set property `itemWidth`. For example:

```
        legend: {
            itemWidth: 120
        },
```

From Highcharts docs: ***itemWidth:*** NumberSince 2.0
The width for each legend item. This is useful in a horizontal layout with many items when you want the items to align vertically.