# Highcharts center legend labels when displaying multiple rows

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Is there a way to center the labels in the legend when they are being displayed on multiple rows.

For example, in the image below, I would like to be able to show the item on the second row (line) as centered rather than left-aligned.

[image: labels]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293332/aligning-the-text-in-legend-in-highcharts

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi I tried that before asking this question and the CSS rules seem to be ignored when I try to center my items on multipe rows, guess I would have to overwrite the "postion:absolute" for each item and position them myself?

Comment: Indeed, that may be the solution - there's no such option like "center items in row" for legend. For positioning you may want to use jQuery or `Element.attr()` (from Highcharts API).